# Cross object SOQL query from Case to Opportunity to User object to get email

Tags: soql

I have created a lookup relationship from case to Opportunity and my aim is to extract the email of the opportunity owner and store it in a field on 'Case' but the query doesn't seem to go right.

Here is the query;

Select Id, status, Opportunity__r.Owner.email, Opportunity__r.Id, Opportunity__r.IsClosed from Case Where Status = 'Closed Won'  OR Status = 'Closed Lost'

Comment: FYI - Opportunity owner field is a lookup to User object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute the query from query editor you will see result like below:

[image]

Try using execute anonymous window to query the result and store it in a variable. Check the owner email and you should able to get it:

```
Case o =[select id,opportunity__r.Name,Opportunity__r.Owner.email from case where id='5003700000CRFeR'];
system.debug(o.Opportunity__r.Owner.email);

Outputs -> myemailid@gmail.com
```